# Clicar num buttom e aparecer um prompt

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um `button`, e pretendo que, ao clicar, apareça um `prompt` a perguntar se quer mesmo sair da página, com 2 opções: Confirmar ou cancelar.

Caso clique em confirmar, ele vai para o link do `button`, caso contrário, o prompt fecha e não acontece nada.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Tem algum código que você já tentou? Já deu uma olhada no `confirm` do `Javascript`? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: Eu queria algo mais simples, sem ter que tar a fazer muitas condiçoes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer com uma tag de link mesmo (`<a></a>`) e a função `confirm` do JavaScript. Exemplo:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente sair?');">Sair do site</a>
```

### Detalhando:

É adicionado o evento `onclick` na tag `a` que retorna o resultado da função `confirm`.

A função `confirm` é nativa do JavaScript, e abre uma janela exibindo o texto passado como parâmetro, um botão de 'OK' e um de 'Cancelar'. Caso o usuário clique em 'OK', a função retorna `true`. Caso o usuário clique em 'Cancelar', a função retorna `false`.

Ao retornar `false` para o evento `onclick`, ele interrompe a execução da ação padrão do elemento, que no caso da tag `a` é a chamada para o link indicado no atributo `href`.

> Obs: Semanticamente, o mais indicado para esta ação seria a utilização da tag `<a></a>`, pois por definição, indica o link da página atual com outra página. Você pode ler mais sobre a definição e uso da tag `a` em: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: Obrigado! Excelente resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer colocando o link da página que deve ser direcionada já no JavaScript:

```js
btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var b = confirm('Tem certeza que quer sair?');
  if (b){
    window.location = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Sair</button>
```

Comment: Eu não pretendo colocar o link no javascript, mas sim no html com href, é possivel?

Comment: Neste caso é melhor utilizar o exemplo do @DiegoMarques e estilizar para o link parecer um botão.

Answer (score 1):

Solução alternativa utilizando um `button`:

```js
function confirmaSaida() {
  var confirmado = confirm("Deseja realmente sair da página?");

  if (confirmado === true) {
      self.location = "https://www.google.com";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Sair da página" onclick="confirmaSaida();" />
```

Colocando o link na `tag input`:

```js
function confirmaSaida() {
  var confirmado = confirm("Deseja realmente sair da página?");

  if (confirmado === true) {
      self.location = document.getElementById("btn").getAttribute("data-link");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="btn" name="btn" type="button" value="Sair da página" onclick="confirmaSaida();" data-link="https://www.google.com" />
```

Comment: Eu não pretendo colocar o link no javascript, mas sim no html com href, é possivel?

Comment: Colocar href no input button não é possível. Uma alternativa seria utilizar uma tag data- custimazada, como: data-link="url". Vou editar a minha resposta com essa opção.